# Network info android ip inverted issue

Tags: java, android, networking, wifimanager

I've got a problem. I'm displaying the network info in my application in this way:

```
// Some wifi info
        d=wifiManager.getDhcpInfo();

        s_dns1="DNS 1: "+intToIp(d.dns1);
        s_dns2="DNS 2: "+intToIp(d.dns2);    
        s_gateway="Default Gateway: "+intToIp(d.gateway);    
        s_ipAddress="IP Address: "+intToIp(d.ipAddress); 
        s_leaseDuration="Lease Time: "+String.valueOf(d.leaseDuration);     
        s_netmask="Subnet Mask: "+intToIp(d.netmask);    
        s_serverAddress="Server IP: "+intToIp(d.serverAddress);
```

all of course using `wifiManager`. Now i have a method to convert the values

```
public String intToIp(int i) {

       return ((i >> 24 ) & 0xFF ) + "." +
           ((i >> 16 ) & 0xFF) + "." +
           ((i >> 8 ) & 0xFF) + "." +
           ( i & 0xFF) ;
        }
```

It works.. But instead displays: `192.168.0.0` it displays `0.0.168.192`.. How can i solve?

Comment: apart from changing the order to i , i >> 8, etc?

Comment: See also http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Formatter.html#formatIpAddress(int)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just invert your intToIp method:

```
public String intToIp(int i) {
   return (i & 0xFF) + "." +
       ((i >> 8 ) & 0xFF) + "." +
       ((i >> 16) & 0xFF) + "." +
       ((i >> 24) & 0xFF);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you already solved it. The bytes are arranged in little endian notation, meaning that the most significant byte (192) is at the last position. What you expect is big endian, which is used by "the humans".

You might read about Endianness [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Just reverse the order in which you extract each byte and you're done.